# Printing 1D array of chars, ints in java using System.out.println(arr)

Tags: java

I am printing a 1d array of chars by using System.out.println(arr) and I get the characters in the array (not space seperated). When I do the same by adding a "/t", the output changes and it now prints the address of the char array.

I tried to print a 1d array of ints using System.out.println(arr), but the results were different and it printed the location of the array in memory.

Please tell what is going on and how is it all implemented.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

class Main3{ 

    public static void main(String[] args)throws java.lang.Exception{
        int[] intArr = {1,2,3,4};
        char[] charArr = {'a' , 'b' };
        System. out.println(intArr);             // prints the address of the intArr
        System. out.println(charArr);            // prints the charArr contents 
        System.out.println("\t" + charArr);      // prints the address of the charArr after a tab
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[PrintStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html) has a [method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println%28char%5B%5D%29) that accepts a `char[]`.

However when you do `"\t" + charArray` java tries to do [String concatenation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.1). To do this it first has to convert `charArray` to a String using the [Object#toString](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) method([JLS 5.1.11](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.11)). Then it passes the String into `println`.

Answer (score 2):

The following print statement:

```
System.out.println(charArr);
```

invokes the [`PrintStream#println(char[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println%28char%5B%5D%29) method. From the documentation:

> The characters are converted into bytes according to the platform's default character encoding, and these bytes are written in exactly the manner of the `write(int)` method.

Whereas the next print statement:

```
System.out.println("\t" + charArr);
```

converts the `charArray` to `String`, by invoking the `toString()` method of `Object` class, as arrays don't override it. And then the method [`PrintStream#println(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println%28java.lang.String%29) is invoked.

So, the above print statement is equivalent to:

```
System.out.println("\t" + charArr.toString());
```

Look into the [`Object#toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) method to see how it forms the string for the array.

Answer (score -1):

The way to access the elements of the array is with bracket notation. So for example if you want the get the int at index 0 of the intArr you could write

```
System.out.println(intArr[0]);
```

where the number in brackets is the index of the element you want or you could iterate over all of them with

```
for(int i = 0; i < intArr.length; i++){
    System.out.println(intArr[i]);
}
```

This will work as long as whats in the array is not an object - in which case it will print the address.